# Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) preview error "cannot preview in this file -- unexpected error occur"

Tags: macos, xcode

```
diagnose -> "messageRepliedWithError("Connecting to launched interactive agent 2467", Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.dt.ultraviolet.service Code=17 "connectToPreviewHost: Failed to connect to 2467: (null)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=connectToPreviewHost: Failed to connect to 2467: (null)}))"
```

The above cited error pops up every time I add new views into the code. It also takes a while for the preview to process but the error pops up. When I click `try again`, sometimes the will re-render and works but only for that time. The new views I add still give me the same error.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]